# Loosely compressing image from outside domain

Tags: php

I check my website speed on pagespeed insights, I get this thing to optimize image:
Losslessly compressing http://img.fkcdn.com/…es-silver-original-imaeb3sv5zpwd2c3.jpeg could save 84.9KiB (18% reduction)
for many images.

Now this is an external server. I have no command over it. How can I optimize this image.

Comment: You can't, really. You _could_ relay the image via your own server, that _would_ allow a compression, but the overhead does not justify that.

Comment: yeah, was expecting the same response, just confirming it. Thanks!!

Comment: If fkcdn is not your server, then it's considered rude to deep link from your site to images stored on their site. Copy the images to your own hosting, and then you'll be free to optimize them however you want.

Answer (score 0):

A very common scenario!

Just copy the images on your own server, since we do not have control over remote servers. Compress them using sites like [Tinypng](http://tinypng.com) or [CompressImage](http://compressimage.pw) and refer them in your HTML.

IF image quality is a concern:

1. load a blurred/compressed/light-weight version of the image from
   your own server
2. lazyload the original image
3. Replace #1 with #2 once
   the load is complete